# iTunes 9 refuses to install on Windows 10 - even after system reset

Tags: itunes, installation, services

I have continued using iTunes 9 ever since it was current, as I find it vastly more user-friendly than subsequent versions. Previously, it has run smoothly on Windows 10. Now, however, it refuses to install on a brand-new PC (even after re-installing Windows).

The error is this: the installer gets most of the way through the process, then displays the message "Service 'IPod Service' (IPod Service) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficent privileges to start system services."

Looking up "iPod Service" in the services list hasn't been helpful: the service refuses to start when told, displaying the message "Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

I have tried this countless times over many days, each time completely uninstalling all Apple-related software (including Bonjour and Quicktime) before attempting again, and the result is always the same. I have run the program as an administrator (even though I was logged in as one anyway), and tried it after disabling all antivirus software - no change.

A lot of Googling has revealed that I am far from the first to have this problem - isolated people have been experiencing this for over ten years. However, not a single page has proposed a solution that works for me.

I'm not an immensely IT-capable person, but I've typically found that I can fix most issues through a combination of research and simple trial and error. This unusually intractable problem has been most frustrating, and I'd have a world of gratitude for anyone who can suggest a solution.